# Why doesn't my python algorithm for checking palindromes work?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

So I was doing [exercise 6 from chapter 7 from Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython007.html#toc76) and it stroke me as odd that this piece of code I wrote as a solution didn't work:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    elif first(word) == last(word):
        is_palindrome(middle(word))
    else:
        return False
```

It doesn't enter any recursion and I don't know why. It returns None for words longer than 1 character of length. Why is this? When the length of the word reaches 1 or less it should return True!
Why doesn't it work?

PS: Here are first, last and middle deffinitions:

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]
```

Comment: You are missing "return" in front of the call to is_palindrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `return`:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    elif first(word) == last(word):
        return is_palindrome(middle(word))  # <--
    else:
        return False
```

So your current snippet is returning `None` once the `elif` block is entered, since you don't have an explicit return statement there. In other words, you *do* compute `is_palindrome(middle(word))`, but you do nothing with the result.

Maybe working through a simple example would help. Consider calling the *original* function with an argument of `'aba'`:

- function called
- `word` is now `'aba'`
- `len(word) <= 1` is `False`, `if`-body not entered.
- `first(word) == last(word)` is `True`, `elif`-body entered:

  - function called recursively:
  - `word` is now `'b'`
  - `len(word) <= 1` is `True`, `if`-body entered:

    - `True` returned
- Return value of recursive call discarded (since we have no `return` in `elif`)
- `None` returned

Comment: @user3182422 I've explained why it doesn't work. Was the explanation unclear?

Comment: What I don't understand is why it doesn't work without the added "return". It seemed more as if you were providing me with a workaround, that's all!

Comment: @user3182422 Well you need return to actually report the function's result to the caller. Without reaching an explicit return, a function returns `None` by default, it's as simple as that. You could ask the same question about `return` in front of `True` and `False`, and the answer is the same.

Comment: You might want to read up on recursion a bit if you don't understand why the `return` is needed..

Answer (score 1):

Add `return`

```
return is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to return the method in 5th line of your function.

```
return is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

should be there instead of

```
 is_palindrome(middle(word))
```